Need examples of problems of the form "Construct a function $f:[0,1] \rightarrow [0,1]$ satisfying properties expressible only with $\leq$".
Let $I$ be the unit interval. I developed a method to simplify problems of the form "Construct a function $f:I \rightarrow I$ satisfying given properties". These properties should only be expressible in the structure $(I,\leq)$, i.e.: not using any properties of $I$ beyond its structure as a dense total ordering. Finding examples of such problems will help me test out my method, so I can iron out any bugs and make it more efficient.
A couple of examples of such a problem would be the trivial "Construct a function that is constant on $I$." to the less trivial "Construct a function $f:I\rightarrow I$ that maps every open interval to the whole of $I$". The latter example satisfies the requirements because the condition can be expressed as "$\forall a \forall b \forall y [(a<b) \implies \exists x (a<x<b \wedge f(x)=y)]$".
Any interesting examples of such problems would be appreciated, and I would be especially happy with a wide range of difficulties in your examples.
Thank you !!

I guess "expressible" means "first-order expressible."

@MichaelGreinecker I value first-order expressible conditions more, but second-order ones would work as well as edge cases. Statements that are first-order expressible but  only with infinitely many statements will also work. You can define constants within $I$ if you want.

somerthing like this?

You have provided a couple of interesting examples. Here's some more simple ones to express in terms of the structure $(I,\le)$:

Construct a function $f:I\rightarrow I$ that is strictly decreasing. Translates to $f:I\rightarrow I,\forall a\in I,b\in I, (a<b \implies f(b)<f(a))$
Construct a function $f: I\rightarrow I$ that is bijective but is not monotonic on any nontrivial subinterval of $I$. Translates to:\begin{equation}
[\forall a \forall b, (f(a)=f(b)\implies a=b)]\land[\forall x\exists a, f(a)=x]\land[\forall a\forall b((a<b)\implies (\exists x,y,z, (a<x<y<z<b)\land[f(y)>\max(f(x),f(z)) \lor f(y)<\min(f(x),f(z))]))]
\end{equation}
(This is fairly complicated to express formally!)
Construct a function $f:I\rightarrow I$ such that $f(f(x))$ is decreasing. Translates to:\begin{equation}
\forall a\forall b,[(a<b)\implies f(f(b))\le f(f(a))]
\end{equation}
Construct a function that has no fixed points, i.e. $\forall a,f(a)\ne a$.
Construct a function whose image is an open interval. Might be expressed as:$$
\exists x \exists y, [(x<y) \land (\forall a, x<f(a)<y)\land (\forall z, (x<z<y \implies \exists c,f(c)=z))]
$$
Construct a function that is periodic under iteration: $$\exists n\in\mathbb{N}, \forall a\in I, f^n(a)=a$$
Construct a function that achieves its minimum. $$
\exists a,\forall x, (f(a)\le f(x))
$$
Construct an idempotent function.$$
\forall a, f(a)=f(f(a))
$$

I also thought of a couple that are more complicated because they make use of the order topology, i.e. the topology generated by open intervals $(a,b) = \{x\mid a<x<b\}$. This topology can be constructed for any totally ordered set, but totally ordered and dense does not imply that a set is topologically equivalent to $[0,1]$, e.g. $\mathbb{Q}\cap [0,1]$ and the long line also have dense total orders.
Construct a function that is continuous. This one is a little tough to express in formal logical terms, but one can express it in purely order-theoretic terms easily enough: For all $a,b$ such that $f(a)<f(b)$, the set $f^{-1}((f(a),f(b)))$ is expressible as a union of open intervals, i.e. there exists $\{(a_i,b_i)\}_{i\in\mathcal{J}}\subset \mathcal{P}(I)$ such that $$
\bigcup_{i\in\mathcal{J}} (a_i,b_i) = f^{-1}((f(a),f(b)))
$$
for some indexing set $\mathcal{J}$. (On $[0,1]$ one can suppose that $\mathcal{J}$ is countable, but this isn't necessarily the case for general sets with a dense total order.)
Construct a function like the Cantor function in that $f(x)$ is continuous, surjective, and the set of points where it is not "flat" has empty interior. To put it more precisely:

$f$ is continuous (see above)
$f$ is surjective, i.e. for all $x\in I$, there exists $a\in I$ such that $f(a)=x$.
There exists a set of intervals $\{(a_i,b_i)\}_{i\in \mathcal{J}}$ such that for all $i\in\mathcal{J}$, $f(x)=f(y)$ for all $x,y\in(a_i,b_i)$, and the set $J=\bigcup_{i\in\mathcal{J}} (a_i,b_i)$ is dense in $I$.


Thank you very much !! I'm hoping my technique outperforms transfinite induction in building functions. Do you know of any examples where transfinite induction doesn't yield a solution?

I can't think of an examples off the cuff. I'll mull it over; that might be a good follow-up Q

A Dedekind cut, hence real numbers in $[0,1]$, can be defined with $\le$ only.
Let's use functions from $[0,1]$ to $\{0,1\}$. Such a function $f$ is a Dedekind cut iff all elements in the preimage of $0$ are lower than all elements in the preimage of $1$. This is expressed by:
$f: I \rightarrow I, \forall a \in I, \forall b \in I, (f(a) \le 0 \vee 1 \le f(a)) \wedge (a \le b \Rightarrow f(a) \le f(b)) $
Note that to be useful, we should restrict $I$ to $\mathbb Q \cap [0,1]$, otherwise we are just defining real numbers by Dedekind cuts of real numbers.
Note also that the definition above allows two different Dedekind cuts for the same real number (or the same element in $\mathbb Q$ if we use $\mathbb Q \cap [0,1]$ as $I$): the one where the real number is the greatest element in $f^{-1}(0)$, and the one where it is the lowest element in $f^{-1}(1)$.
